# How can I safely extract a function from gnarly C++ code?

Tags: c++, refactoring, legacy-code

Suppose I have a 5000-line-long, deeply nested function, and I want to extract a 1000-line block into a new function.

In Java and C# I can let ReSharper, IntelliJ, and Visual C# handle the analysis required to safely extract a method, no matter how long and gnarly the code is. I can be confident that they won't change the behavior of the code, even if it's too complex for me to understand with my small brain.

The available C++ tools are not able to give me the same level of confidence. CLion, ReSharper, and Visual Assist will all introduce behavior changes when they extract a method.

What are my options?

Comment: This might be more interesting if you included examples of the the "gnarly C++" code that you are trying to "extract".

Comment: @NeilButterworth Added a sentence about that.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use this recipe, based on Tennent's Correspondence Principle. You may apply it to a whole block (surrounded by braces) or to an `if`, `while`, or `for` statement (which create their own scopes).

## 1. **Introduce a lambda and call it**

**Surround the block** in question with:

```
[&]() {
    // original code
}();
```

**Compile the file.** Possible errors:

- **not all control paths return a value.** You have an early return. Back up and either Eliminate Early Return/Continue/Break or extract something different.
- **a break/continue statement may only be used within...**  You have a break/continue. Back up and either Eliminate Early Return/Continue/Break or extract something different.

**Check the new lambda for any return statements.** If there are any returns and it's obvious that all code paths return, then add a return statement on the next line after the lambda. If there are any returns and it's not obvious that all code paths return, then back up and either Eliminate Early Return/Continue/Break or try extracting something different.

## 2. Introduce Variable on the lambda

i.e.

```
[&]() {
    // ...
}();
```

becomes:

```
auto Applesauce = [&]() {
    // ...
};
Applesauce();
```

**Compile** to make sure you didn't typo.

## 3. Set the return type

Set the return type on the lambda (even if it's `void`). In Visual Studio, the tooltip over `auto` will tell you the type.

i.e.:

```
auto Applesauce = [&]() -> SOMETYPE {
    // ...
};
```

Compile to make sure you got the return type correct.

## 4. Capture explicitly

Replace `[&]` with `[this]` (or `[]` in a free function) and compile.

For each error about a variable that must be captured:
 - Copy the variable name
 - Paste it in to the capture list, prefixed with `&`
 - Repeat until green.

i.e.:

```
auto Applesauce = [this, &foo]() -> void {
    cout << foo;
};
```

The order of the capture list will influence the order of the parameters of the final function. If you want the parameters in a particular order, now is a good time to reorder the capture list.

## 5. Convert captures to parameters

For each captured local variable (except `this`)
 - Go to the definition of the variable
 - Copy the variable declaration (e.g. `Column* pCol`)
 - Paste in to the lambda parameter list
 - Make the parameter const and by-reference
 - Remove the variable from the capture list
 - Pass the variable in to the call
 - Compile.

i.e.:

```
Column* pCol = ...
auto Applesauce = [&pCol]() -> void { cout << pCol->name(); };
Applesauce();
```

becomes

```
Column* pCol = ...
auto Applesauce = [](Column*& pCol) -> void { cout << pCol->name(); };
Applesauce(pCol);
```

## 6. Convert lambda to function

If `this` is captured, use 6A.
If `this` is not captured, use 6B.

### 6A. Convert this-bound lambda to member function

- Cut the lambda statement and paste it outside the current function
- Remove `= [this]`
- Copy the signature line
- Add `SomeClass::`
- Paste the signature in to the class declaration in a private section.
- Compile

i.e.:

```
auto SomeClass::Applesauce () const -> void {
    // ...
};
```

### 6B. Convert non-this Lambda to free function

- Cut the lambda statement and paste it above the current function.
- Remove `= []`
- Compile

Comment: I think the question title should be changed to *"how can lambda be used to refactor code"* because lambda not only helps you to "extract" *free* and *member* functions, rather helps you to refactor code in general, e.g I often use immediately-invoked lambda to initialize `const` local variables when initialization requires multi-line computation; such immediately-invoked lambda (IIL) doesn't always become functions, as they are one-time used. Also, since I use IIL for initialization, I also get opportunity to make my objects `const` (if they need not to be immutable).